# What do these parts of this SPARQL query mean?

Tags: sparql

I have three questions about the following SPARQL query:

```sql
PREFIX basekb:<http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?p2 ?o where {
   basekb:m.06y3r ?p1 ?cvt .
   ?cvt ?p2 ?o .
   ?cvt basekb:freebase.type_hints.mediator true.
}
```

My questions are about the following parts of the query:

1. **`basekb:m.06y3r ?p1 ?cvt`**: all the properties and objects of `basekb:m.06y3r` are assigned respectively to `?p1`and `?cvt`?
2. **`?cvt ?p2 ?o`**: all the properties of `?cvt` will be assigned to `?o`
3. **`?cvt basekb: freebase.type_hints.mediator true:`** check if the predicate is equal to 1

---

## Minor update

Suppose that I want to know the employment history of `basekb:m.06y3r`. Suppose also that I know the set of objects in the database that have **freebase.type_hints.mediator true**.

```
select ?cvt ?p2 ?o
where {
   basekb:m.06y3r basekb:people.person.employment_history ?cvt.
   ?cvt ?p2 ?o
}
```

This query will output the following subset of triples :

```
    :m.04j3rn8  :type   :business.employment_tenure
    :m.04j3rn0  :type   :business.employment_tenure
    :m.04j3rng  :type   :business.employment_tenure
```

The type of m.04j3rn8 is `business.employment_tenure` which is actually a `mediator` so it has `freebase.type_hints.mediator true`. Can I check if  `business.employment_tenure` **is included* in the **set** of objects in the database having `freebase.type_hints.mediator true`.

---

### Pseudo-code

```
select ?cvt ?p2 ?o
    where {
       basekb:m.06y3r basekb:people.person.employment_history ?cvt.
       ?cvt ?p2 ?o
       IF ?o  belongs to the set of objects that are considered as mediators then output results.
    }
```

According to this [link](http://lod.openlinksw.com/describe/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frdf.basekb.com%2Fns%2Fbusiness.employment_tenure) business.employment_tenure has the following property:

**is** http://rdf.basekb.com/public/knownAs **of**  **Employment tenure**.

it has the following types `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class`. Sheesh freebase is weird

---

## Solution

I was able to write this query but don't know why it's so slow. It gave the correct results. I was able to extract the compound value types.

```
PREFIX basekb:<http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>


select distinct ?history ?p3 ?o3 where {
   basekb:m.06y3r basekb:people.person.employment_history ?history .
   ?history ?property ?value;
   ?p3 ?o3.
   ?value rdfs:label ?label. 
   ?s ?p2 ?label;
   basekb:freebase.type_hints.mediator true .
}
```

---

This query wont produce any result. It's totally right but isn't working.I need the ID of ?value in order to check if it's a CVT.

```
PREFIX basekb:<http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX key:<http://rdf.basekb.com/key/>


select distinct ?history ?p3 ?o3 where {
   basekb:m.06y3r basekb:people.person.employment_history ?history .
   ?history ?property ?value;
   ?p3 ?o3.
   ?value basekb:freebase.type_hints.mediator true .
   FILTER(basekb:m.06y3r != ?o3)
}
```

Comment: What's the point of ?s and ?p2 in this query?  Don't you want to check whether *?value* has the type hints mediator true?

Comment: yes @JoshuaTaylor I know. But the problem is that base on this [link](http://lod.openlinksw.com/describe/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frdf.basekb.com%2Fns%2Fbusiness.employment_tenure). I cannot get its property **freebase.type_hints.mediatorù** which is In other entity. I Have to get its ID by using the label then In the end I check if basekb:freebase.type_hints.mediator true

Comment: If you keep changing the question, then it's not really worth anyone's time to answer it, because responses based on one version no longer make sense after the edit.  Anyhow, the link in your comment only has one property/value.  Then that value has a mediator value, but notice that it's "Mediator  1(xsd:integer)".  As I stressed in my answer, a number is not the same thing as a boolean.  If you search for "mediator true", you **won't get** "mediator 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 1 and 2 correct, but 3 is a little bit off.  The pattern

```
?cvt basekb:freebase.type_hints.mediator true.
```

matches when the value of ?cvt has a value for the property **basekb:freebase.type_hints.mediator**, and the value is **true**.  RDF has datatyped literal values, and boolean value are not the same as numbers.  In RDF, the number 1 is not the same as the boolean true, and there's no automatic conversion in your query like there might be in some programming languages.  The pattern `?x ?y 1` will match triples where the object is 1, and the pattern `?x ?y true` will match triples where the object is true.

Based on the update to your question, it sounds like you want a query like:

```sql
select ?history ?property ?value  where {
   basekb:m.06y3r basekb:people.person.employment_history ?history .
   ?history ?property ?value .
   ?history ?p ?o .
   ?o :type ?type .
   ?type freebase.type_hints.mediator true .
}
```

This selects those each history, and all of its values, such that the history has *some* value which has a type that is a mediator.

You can make that a bit shorter with some property paths.  **(<>|!<>)** is a wildcard property, **a/b/c** means a sequence path, and **^p** means **p** in the reverse direction.  You can end up with this:

```sql
select ?history ?property ?value where {
   ?history ^basekb:people.person.employment_history basekb:m.06y3r ;
            ?property ?value ;
            (<>|!<>)/:type/freebase.type_hints.mediator true .
}
```

Comment: Can I elaborate more on this question please?

Comment: Can you? Or do you want elaboration on the answer?  You can certainly ask for clarification...

Comment: Only if ?cvt have a property  freebase.type_hints.mediator equal to 1 then the results will be shown on the screen. Else nothing

Comment: Not "equal to 1", but "equal to true".  1 and true are not the same thing.  1 is a number, and there are lots of numbers.  true is truth value and there are only two of those (true and false).

Comment: I updated the question. sorry it has been bothering me for the last couple of weeks

Comment: If you follow this link http://lod.openlinksw.com/describe/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frdf.basekb.com%2Fns%2Fbusiness.employment_tenure you will see that **employment_tenure** doesn't have freebase.type_hints.mediator true . I have to go one more step in order to get it. Let me clarify it

Comment: I was able to modify it. But the query is so slow. Can you check the solution?